# Unable to return pointer to array C++ visual studio

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I am brand new to C++ and am struggling with the idea of using arrays and returning pointers.

I have a class `Student` in a `.h` file:

```cpp
class Student {
    public:
        // stuff
        int* GetNumDaysPerCourse() const;
        // stuff

    private:
        //stuff
        int numDaysPerCourse[3];
        // stuff
};
```

And I am trying to implement it in a `.cpp` file:

```cpp
int* Student::GetNumDaysPerCourse() const {
    return numDaysPerCourse;
}
```

But I am getting an error saying:

> return value type does not match the function type

I am confused because looking at other questions, this looks like a valid way to do this.

So, how do I return a class member array using a getter in C++?

Comment: Do you want people to be able to change values of the array that the pointer points to?

Comment: Please try to create a proper [mcve] to show us, and then copy-paste the full and complete build output of that example into your question.

Comment: `error: invalid conversion from ‘const int*’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive] return numDaysPerCourse;` is the error I see since it wasn't included in the question.

Comment: By the way, returning pointers to internal data could lead to problems if the caller doesn't use the pointer correctly (modify data it should not modify, go out of bounds, etc.). I recommend you use `std::array<int, 3>` for the array, and return either by constant reference or by value.

Comment: @NathanOliver they should not be able to change the values of the array that the pointer points to. I am creating a setter that will handle any changes

Comment: @Mr.Spock Okay.  Then you will want option 2 from Remy Lebeau's answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I try to [compile this code](https://ideone.com/AZI6FD), I get this error:

> error: invalid conversion from ‘const int*’ to ‘int*’

This is because `GetNumDaysPerCourse()` is **const-qualified**, so its `this` pointer is pointing at a `const Student` object, and thus its `numDaysPerCourse` member is treated as `const` data.  You can't assign the address of const data to a pointer-to-non-const (without an explicit type-cast, that is, but don't do that), as that would grant permission for outside code to modify data that is (potentially) stored in read-only memory.

So, you need to either:

- drop the `const` qualifier from `GetNumDaysPerCourse()`:

```cpp
public:
    ...
    int* GetNumDaysPerCourse();
    ...

private:
    ...
    int numDaysPerCourse[3];
    ...
};
```

```cpp
int* Student::GetNumDaysPerCourse() {
    return numDaysPerCourse;
}
```

- make `GetNumDaysPerCourse()` return a pointer-to-const:

```cpp
public:
    ...
    const int* GetNumDaysPerCourse() const;
    ...

private:
    ...
    int numDaysPerCourse[3];
    ...
};
```

```cpp
const int* Student::GetNumDaysPerCourse() const {
    return numDaysPerCourse;
}
```

- combine the two approaches to provide both const and non-const access to the same array, depending on whether the object that `GetNumDaysPerCourse()` is being called on is mutable or read-only:

```cpp
public:
    ...
    int* GetNumDaysPerCourse();
    const int* GetNumDaysPerCourse() const;
    ...

private:
    ...
    int numDaysPerCourse[3];
    ...
};
```

```cpp
int* Student::GetNumDaysPerCourse() {
    return numDaysPerCourse;
}

const int* Student::GetNumDaysPerCourse() const {
    return numDaysPerCourse;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to modify the pointer after calling `int *GetNumDaysPerCourse() const;`

You can modify your class and your implementation as follows:

```cpp
class Student {
public:
    // stuff
    const int *GetNumDaysPerCourse() const;
    // stuff

private:
    //stuff
    int numDaysPerCourse[3];
    // stuff
};
```

The `.cpp` file:

```cpp
const int *Student::GetNumDaysPerCourse() const {
    return numDaysPerCourse;
}
```